# Maven: Generating zip of a bunch of files to my webapp dir

Tags: maven

It would be trivial in a Makefile, but I don't know how to do it in Maven.

In my repository I have a bunch of files in my `src/main/resources` files that I'd like to put inside a zip file. The zip file should be updated every time any of these files are changed. The zip file must be generated inside my `src/main/webapp` directory.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a zip from a bunch of files using the Maven Assembly Plugin. The zip will be recreated *every time*, not only if you change something.

Furthermore, you usually *don't* create files into `src/...` but only into `target/...` so that your src stays clean in the build process.